Running multiple instances of selenium is generating connection error
I am running selenium automation scripts using python3, on linux and undetected_chrome.
I am also using proxies.
When I run only one instances it works fine and does the job however the moment a second instance is launched I get this error :
2024-04-30 00:09:28 - ERROR - HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost',
port=44073): Max retries exceeded with url:
/session/2488e939aa54121cb42b165948495489/actions (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x7debd7c86fb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
Connection refused'))

Despite the proxies are changing with each driver.
I have trying all kinds of solutions I could think of around it.

I have moved into different scripts and run them from different terminals.
I have launched one instance with proxy and once instance without a proxy.
I have launched automation towards scrapeme website to see if the website is blocking me but the same thing happened.
This is all I could think of but I did not get anywhere.
I am really bugged and I do not know where the error is actually is.
Can you please help me with this.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Possibly helpful or related MaxRetryError Selenium

This solution uses SeleniumBase UC Mode instead of undetected-chromedriver to spin up multiple simultaneous web browsers with stealth: (pip install seleniumbase)
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from seleniumbase import Driver
sys.argv.append("-n")  # Activate SB thread-locking as needed

def launch_driver(url):
    driver = Driver(uc=True)
    try:
        driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
        driver.sleep(2)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

urls = ['https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in' for i in range(3)]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(urls)) as executor:
    for url in urls:
        executor.submit(launch_driver, url)

Be sure to swap the example URL (that uses bot-detection software) with the URL that you want.

It was indeed an issue with undetected-chrome as the moment I changed the driver to use seleniumbase it worked real fine and handled timeouts properly without giving this bug again. Though I did not use the exact script you provided but the seleniumbase suggestion was the game changer and it made the code working again.
